# Condition for the complex conjugation to be in Gal(P/k)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $P\in k[X]$ be a separable polynomial over a field k.

if P has a unique real root in $\overline{k}$ then complex conjugation $\epsilon$ verifies $\epsilon \in Gal(P/k)$.

To which extent is this a true statement regarding the degree $n$ of $P$?

I think $n$ needs to be odd for this to be true in order for $\epsilon$ to stabilize any splitting field of P over k?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean $k \subset \mathbb{R}$ so for any field $\mathbb{C} \supset L \supset k$ the complex conjugaison $\varepsilon$ is a field isomorphism $L \to \varepsilon(L)$ leaving $k$ fixed. Now if $L$ is the splitting field of $P \in k[x]$ then so is $ \varepsilon(L)$ and hence $L =  \varepsilon(L)$ and $\varepsilon \in Gal(L/k)$.

Comment: I mean the following: let's take  $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $n=3$. Suppose P has a unique real root and 2 complex roots. we know that for a splitting field of P: $\epsilon(L) = L$ because the two complex roots are conjugates. can we generalize this for any n?

Comment: Yes. All you need is that $P(a) =0  \Leftrightarrow 0 = \varepsilon(P(a)) = P(\varepsilon(a))$. So $P$ splits completely in $L$ iff it splits completely in $\varepsilon(L)$, and $L$ is the smallest such field implies so is $\varepsilon(L)$ and $L = \varepsilon(L)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, then complex conjugation gives an element of the Galois group of *any* polynomial $P\in k[X]$ whatsoever.  Indeed, if $L\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is the splitting field of $P$ over $k$, then complex conjugation maps $L$ to itself (since it maps $k$ to itself and thus permutes the roots of $P$) and so is an automorphism of $L$.